# How to create 100 Jira tickets with different descritptions?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I have to create 100 Jira tickets. creating manually is going to take atleast 10 days, if I daily create one. Is there a way I can automate this or any trick which I can use to minimize the manual effort ?

Comment: Jira does have an API so you could write a script that converts whatever source you have into jira tickets.

Answer (score 0):

They have a really great REST API for doing such type of things.

Check this out: https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-create-issue

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what data you have for your "100 issues".  One really simple way to do it is to use one of the importers.  There's a load that import from specific systems, but it's well worth a look at the "import from CSV".  If you have a file with 1 line for each issue to be imported, it's a doddle.